# Angular: Changing mat-button-toggle-group to allow uncheck option

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using the mat-button-toggle-group and reactive forms.  like this:

```
                  <mat-button-toggle-group formControlName="myCtl" (click)="choiceClick($event)" class="col2 v-toggle short formAnswer" aria-label="Font Style">
                    <mat-button-toggle [value]="true">Yes</mat-button-toggle>
                    <mat-button-toggle [value]="false">No</mat-button-toggle>
                  </mat-button-toggle-group>
```

It's working well, however I want the user to be able to uncheck Yes/No to leave the button in the unchecked state. Currently, once you click on it, you cannot unclick it, and the user is forced to select an option.  I tried doing (click)="choiceClick($event)" but I can't seem to get the parent buttonGroup object from the event to reset it.  Also not sure how to check to see if already-selected button was clicked.

Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

You can reset the toggle button by setting the the value of the control in angular ts file directly like this

```
this.formgroup.controls.myCtl.patchValur("");
```

This way you can reset value

Comment: but I can't do this generically in all my toggle buttons right? So that when the user clicks a toggle button that is already clicked, it unchecks it.

Comment: You have to make a turn around for it

Comment: sorry, your answer is completely unhelpful.